# Using where() on a collection in Streambuilder keeps returning null

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-web

I am trying to find all documents in a collection the fit a certain criteria, and have that in a Streambuilder so that I can create a table using data from all the documents it returns. But my stream inside the Streambuilder keeps returning null for my query in Flutter. I try the same query in Python and it returns the right docs. Is it not possible to have a where query in a streambuilder? For reference, this is for a web app.

Here's my code

```
class ContainerCustomerTable extends StatefulWidget {
  final company;

  ContainerCustomerTable({this.company});
  @override
  _ContainerCustomerTableState createState() => _ContainerCustomerTableState();
}

class _ContainerTableState extends State<ContainerCustomerTable> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
        stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(widget.company).where('some_criteria', isEqualTo: true).snapshots(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          print(snapshot);
          QuerySnapshot docSnapshot = snapshot.data;
          if (docSnapshot != null) {
            return  Text('test1');
          } else{
            return LoadingIndicator();
          }

        }

    );
```

I am printing out the snapshot just to check what it returns and it gives me this

```
AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot>(ConnectionState.active, null, [cloud_firestore/unknown] NoSuchMethodError: invalid member on null: 'includeMetadataChanges')
```

So it's returning null for that query, but again the same query in python produces the right results. What am I doing wrong?

And for the record, when I run the following, it works:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(widget.company).doc('some_doc').snapshots()
```

but for some reason, when I just run the snapshot on the collection or on the where, I get the error posted above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. My syntax was just fine, it was the firestore js package that was wrong. If you are using firestore for a web app, use this version in your web/index.html:

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.20.0/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
```

not the last version 8.0.2, when I downgraded everything worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Note that you are also printing the snapshot and assigning the docSnapshot before it has data here:

```
print(snapshot);
QuerySnapshot docSnapshot = snapshot.data;
if (docSnapshot != null) {
   return  Text('test1');
} else{
   return LoadingIndicator();
}
```

For safety I would go like:

```
if (snapshot.hasData) {
   print(snapshot);
   QuerySnapshot docSnapshot = snapshot.data;
   return  Text('test1');
} else{
   return LoadingIndicator();
}
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I was just printing it there to try and debug what was wrong. ultimately my code wasn't wrong i just need to change the version of firestore.js